# Cannot locate node of type [state_publisher]

Tags: ros, robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently running ROS Noetic (installed with apt) on Debian 10, I tried to follow the URDF tutorial : http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20urdf%20with%20robot_state_publisher.

However I get the following error message when launching the display.launch file :

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [robot_state_publisher/state_publisher]: Cannot locate node of type [state_publisher] in package [robot_state_publisher]. Make sure file exists in package path and permission is set to executable (chmod +x)
```

I tried every other solution I could find online but nothing works for me... Maybe I missed something.

Thanks in advance !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357672/cannot-locate-node-of-type-%5Bstate_publisher%5D/) by [nodigue](https://answers.ros.org/users/56839/nodigue/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2020-07-20

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) on 2020-07-21**:
do you have the package correctly installed?

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-robot-state-publisher
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`state_publisher` was a deprecated alias for the node named `robot_state_publisher`. It was removed in https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher/pull/87 which is included in the ROS Noetic release of that package.  Change `type="state_publisher"` to `type="robot_state_publisher"`.

```
<!-- Change state_publisher  -->
<!-- <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" /> -->
<!-- To robot_state_publisher -->
<node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" />
```

I [updated the tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/action/info/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20urdf%20with%20robot_state_publisher?action=diff&rev2=24&rev1=23).

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2020-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 31

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nodigue](https://answers.ros.org/users/56839/nodigue/) on 2020-07-21**:
Thanks ! It works now :)

**Comment by [deficos](https://answers.ros.org/users/99573/deficos/) on 2022-03-16**:
Thanks. It works perfectly now.